# Underscore.js get an array of unique objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have 2 arrays of objects. There are duplicates between the arrays. I want to merge them into 1 array of all **unique** objects (so no duplicates).

How can I do this by comparing the "id" of each object?

Underscore.js has a method called `_.uniq()`. It looks to be correct, but I can't get the syntax for the "iterator" argument correct.

```
var firstArray = [{ id: 1, name: "foo"}, { id: 2, name: "bar" }];
var secondArray = [{ id: 2, name: "boop" }, { id: 3, name: "baz" }];

firstArray.push(secondArray);
var myUniqueArray = _.uniq(firstArray, false, ???);

myUniqueArray // [{ id: 1, name: "foo"}, { id: 2, name: "bar" }, { id: 3, name: "baz" }];
```

Comment: [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items) and you do not really need to use an external library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with [`_.uniq`](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) method used with second parameter of the property name to be used to filter items:

```js
var firstArray = [{ id: 1, name: "foo"}, { id: 2, name: "bar" }];
var secondArray = [{ id: 2, name: "boop" }, { id: 3, name: "baz" }];

var result = _.uniq(firstArray.concat(secondArray), 'id');

alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do it:

```
var myUniqueArray = _.uniq(firstArray.concat(secondArray), false, function (obj) {
    return obj.id;
});
```

The iteratee here will produce a value on which uniqueness is checked, in this case the `id` property value.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakeclarkson/gmupx6qx/).